# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo (android)

Tags: android

I am getting this error, please help me.

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newandrojenaproject/com.example.newandrojenaproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.newandrojenaproject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String str = extractUsingSparql("<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Babur>");
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if(!str.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
        t.setText(str);
        else
            t.setText("Null Value Returned");
    }

     public static String extractUsingSparql(String url){

            String abstract1= "";
            String var = "abstract";
            String r="";

            String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
            String query = "SELECT ?abstract WHERE { { "+url+" <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract. FILTER langMatches( lang(?abstract), 'en') } } ";
            //Abstract
            Query q = QueryFactory.create(query, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
            QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service, q);
            try{
            ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();
            while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
                QuerySolution solution = resultSet.next();
                if (solution.get(var) == null) {

                      System.out.println("{null}");
                      r = "null";

                    } else if (solution.get(var).isLiteral()) {

                      System.out.println (solution.getLiteral(var).toString());
                     r= solution.getLiteral(var).toString();
                    } else {
                      System.out.println(solution.getResource(var).getURI());
                      r = solution.getResource(var).getURI();
                    }
            }
            } 
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally
            {
                qe.close();
            }
            return r;
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not using any other activity. I am using androjena and ARQoid libraries for sparql queries. I don't know where actually the error is and how to solve it!

Here are the errors (LogCat output):

```
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newandrojenaproject/com.example.newandrojenaproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.example.newandrojenaproject.MainActivity.extractUsingSparql(MainActivity.java:56)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.example.newandrojenaproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-19 13:00:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What line is `NullPointerException` on? You're trying to use a null object there.

Comment: @Tushar, I don't know about the line number since there is no indication of line numbers in the logCat and debugger. I have added the logCat (Error list) output in my question.

Comment: The `:56` in the logcat next to `MainActivity.java` is the line number. That means you're probably passing a null object to `println` on that line inside function `extractUsingSparql`

Comment: @Tushar, Thanks. Yes after removing println statement, it is not throwing null pointer exception but it is not even displayin anything on the output scree. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As you may see from the log file, the error is located in the 16th row of the MainActivity.java.

It's caused because `t`(textView) is equal to `null`. 
It may be caused by some kind of mess in references, so, try to clean and refresh your project.
`Project -> Clean` in eclipse.